# The different renewal price in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

What is the better (right) way to have different renewal price for Stripe Billing?

I need to make a subscription plan that will have $200 for the first month and then $50 for subsequent months.

Comment: Voting to close this as it's a customer service question for Stripe, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You basically are implementing a setup fee.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#adding-upcoming-invoice-items

> **Adding an extra charge or discount on a subscription’s first invoice**
>
> Include a one-time charge or discount to the first subscription invoice by adding an invoice item to the customer before creating the subscription. The resulting invoice item will be attached to the customer and automatically included in the first invoice created:
>
> ```
> \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create([
>     'amount' => 1000,
>     'currency' => 'usd',
>     'customer' => 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
>     'description' => 'One-time setup fee',
> ]);
> ```